# Reasons for /etc/init.d/crond not running

Tags: linux, logging, cron, init.d

What can be the possible reasons for /etc/init.d/crond not running?

How to debug this ?

What the log files that can be looked up to debug this ?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with "not running"? did you schedule something? In case I suggest to link what you have done.

Which distribution are you using? Logging facility can change depending on distribution

Answer (score 0):

Please check:-

tailf /var/log/cron
and
tailf /var/log/messages

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check file permissions, few days ago one of my init files wasn't running, `chmod +x /path/to/file` solved it.

Also it would be great to post more data: OS version, file content, content of `grep -i crond /var/log/messages | tail -n 20`